# In Java,operator precedence, increment and decrement, why isn't the first println statement executed?

Tags: java

```
class Example{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int x=99;
        if(x++==x){
            System.out.println("x++==x : "+x); //Why this code line is not run?
        }
        if(++x==x ){
            System.out.println("++x==x : "+x); 
        }
    }
}
```

Why isn't the first `println` statement executed?

Comment: Operands are evaluted left to right. The left hand side of the `==` is 99, and has the side effect of incrementing `x`, so the right hand side is 100.

Comment: "The left-hand operand of a binary operator appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the right-hand operand is evaluated." https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7

Comment: Please explain why you think that it should be executed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The differece between `i++` and `++i` is very simple.

- `i++` - means exactly **first get the value and then increment it for the further usage**
- `++i` - means exactly **first increment the value and use the incremented value**

Following the shippet `x++ == x` means following:

- Analyze expression from left to the right
- Get `x = 99` as the left operand and use it in the expression
- Increment `x` and thus `x == 100`
- Get `x = 100` as the right operand (note it is already incremented)
- `99 != 100`

Following the shippet `++x == x` means following:

- Analyze expression from left to the right
- Get `x = 99` as the left operand
- Increment `x` and thus `x == 100` and use it in the expression
- Get `x = 100` as the right operand (note it is already incremented)
- `100 == 100`

You can see all these logic. E.g. not experienced developer cannot know these details. Therefore the **best practice** is to avoid such increments in the expression. **Just do it before** the expression in the single line. In this case the logic will be straight forward and you get much less problems.

Answer (score 6):

The operands of an expression are evaluated left to right.

In the expression `x++ == x`, first `x++` is evaluated. It increments `x` by `1`, but returns the original value of `x`. So `x++` returns `99`.

Then `x` is evaluated, which returns `100` (since it was incremented by `x++`).

Since `99` is not equal to `100`, this condition evaluates to `false`.

If you change the expression to `x==x++`, you'll get `true`.